# LAN not working after windows 8 installation

Tags: windows-8

I recently upgraded to Windows 8 but my LAN network is not working. In the network troubleshooting it shows this:

[image]

It worked well earlier.

I tried changing the DNS server to google's DNS (8.8.8.8) and it is still not working.

Comment: Can you ping your router. If that works, try pinging a machine on the internet by IP address. (Ping 8.8.8.8 would do.). If that does not work then you probably do not have a working internet connection.

Comment: What do you see if you open an command prompt and type `ipconfig /all` ?

Comment: Also, try disabling IPv6, and if you use anything from Apple, look for a service called "Bonjour" and try disabling that. `[edit]`In fact, as I think about it this sounds enough like IPv6 that I'm gonna add that as an answer.

Comment: I can ping computers in my own network but not outside. The network works on other comps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had bumped into a similar problem. This solution worked for me.

Check your default gateway using `ipconfig` (type `ipconfig` in cmd). If your default gateway is set to 0.0.0.0 then you must remove it.

Type `route delete 0.0.0.0`, that should work.

If not type `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt` followed by `netsh winsock reset c:\winsock.txt`. Restart your computer, that should work.

Also disable ipv6 to be sure.

Reference: http://www.timdavis.com.au/general/windows-7-default-gateway-0-0-0-0-problem/

Answer (score 0):

Try [disabling IPv6](http://www.techunboxed.com/2012/08/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-8.html) on the network adapter.

Comment: Didnt work. Still same issue.